# org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate entity descriptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

While trying to solve a certain problem, I used this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739712/21960620

However, when I make a POST request to Company, it throws an exception org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate entity descriptor.

```
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate entity descriptor: com.solanke.spring6jobboardrest.domains.AppUser$AppUserBuilder
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.getEntityDescriptor(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:435) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.requireEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2271) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1173) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getReference(SessionImpl.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy129.getReference(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy129.getReference(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.solanke.spring6jobboardrest.mappers.ReferenceMapper.map(ReferenceMapper.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.solanke.spring6jobboardrest.mappers.AppUserMapperImpl.toAppUser(AppUserMapperImpl.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.solanke.spring6jobboardrest.mappers.CompanyMapperImpl.companyDtoToCompany(CompanyMapperImpl.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.solanke.spring6jobboardrest.services.CompanyServiceImpl.saveNewCompany(CompanyServiceImpl.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.solanke.spring6jobboardrest.controllers.CompanyController.createCompany(CompanyController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
```

ReferenceMapper class

```
@Component
public class ReferenceMapper {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @ObjectFactory
    public <T> T map(@NonNull final Long id, @TargetType Class<T> type) {
        return entityManager.getReference(type, id);
    }
}
```

Generated-sources AppUserMapperImpl

```
    @Override
    public AppUser toAppUser(Long id) {
        if ( id == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AppUser.AppUserBuilder appUser = referenceMapper.map( id, AppUser.AppUserBuilder.class );

        appUser.id( id );

        return appUser.build();
    }
```

Generated-sources CompanyMapperImpl

```
    @Override
    public Company companyDtoToCompany(CompanyDto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Company.CompanyBuilder company = Company.builder();

        company.adminProfile( appUserMapper.toAppUser( dto.getUserId() ) );
        company.id( dto.getId() );
        company.companyName( dto.getCompanyName() );
        company.description( dto.getDescription() );

        return company.build();
    }
```

CompanyDto class

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompanyDto {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String companyName;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Long userId;

}
```

But, in the case where I remove **@Builder** from AppUser entity class, the exception is not thrown, and my question is why does it work after removing @Builder and why it does not work with this annotation.